How to update One lake Delta table with source as event Stream
Below is my Data flow
AzureEventHub-->FabricEventStream --->OneLakeDelta Table
Above flow is working fine for me. The only place i am stuck in is, I am not able to update rows in delta table.
For that I need to use PySpark structured streaming.
I am exploring if is there any option or way to update Delta Table in Event Stream.

Use Delta Lake's capabilities to update the Delta table based on the processed data. Delta's merge functionality is to merge the new data with the existing data in the Delta table.


The only place I am stuck in is, I am not able to update rows in delta table.

Use the foreachBatch function to update rows in a Delta table using PySpark structured streaming. It allows you to perform custom operations (such as upserts) on each micro-batch of data.
Table streaming reads and writes

Below is Spark job to read from Azure Event Hub.

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from delta.tables import *

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("DeltaLakeUpdate") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Event Hub configurations
eventHubConnectionString = "<EventHubConnectionString>"
eventHubConf = {
    'eventhubs.connectionString': eventHubConnectionString,
    'eventhubs.consumerGroup': '$Default'
}

# Read from Event Hub
eventStreamDF = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("eventhubs") \
    .options(**eventHubConf) \
    .load()

Below is the function to perform upserts (merge operations) on the Delta table

Table deletes, updates, and merges

def upsertToDelta(microBatchOutputDF, batchId):
    deltaTablePath = "abfss://<container>@<account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path_to_delta_table>"
    deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, deltaTablePath)
    
    # Perform UPSERT (MERGE) operation
    deltaTable.alias("target").merge(
        microBatchOutputDF.alias("source"),
        "target.id = source.id"  # Assuming 'id' is the primary key
    ).whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
     .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
     .execute()

#Use `foreachBatch` to apply the upsert function on each micro-batch
query = parsedDF.writeStream \
    .format("delta") \
    .foreachBatch(upsertToDelta) \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "abfss://<container>@<account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path_to_checkpoint>") \
    .start()

